# Subtracting two times in libre office base

Tags: libreoffice, date-time, query, libreoffice-base

How can I subtract two times in a query in libre office base?  For instance, 10:30 - 9:00 should give 1:30.  Thanks.

EDIT: As it says in the question, I am having this problem in "base", not with the libre office spreadsheet.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is it not working? Have you set the format for the cells?

Comment: I did a straight subtraction, as in the question.  It gave me an error regarding wrong data type.

Comment: Are you cells actually formatted at `Time`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad  Yes.

Comment: Are you typing `10:30 - 9:00` in a single cell? What happens if you have `10:30` in one cell, `9:00` in another and a formula in a third?

Comment: What engine - [embedded HSQLDB 1.8](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/FAQ_(Base)#So_why_should_I_avoid_.27embedded_databases.27.3F) or a better setup such as split MySQL?  My answer assumes the former.

Comment: @JimK  Really don't know.  How do you tell?  Thanks.

Comment: If you do not know how the file was created, then see my edited answer to find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('hour', "t1", "t2") || ':' || MOD(DATEDIFF('minute', "t1", "t2"),60)
FROM "Table1"
```

Result:

```
1:30
```

It's easier to show the difference as 90 minutes.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('minute', "t1", "t2")
FROM "Table1"
```

Documentation: [HSQLDB 1.8 Built-in Functions and Stored Procedures](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/guide.html#N1251E)

**EDIT**:

To determine the engine, try *Edit -> Database -> Properties*.  However, the option is disabled for my example that uses an embedded setup.

So, I unzipped the .odb file and opened `database/properties`.

```
#HSQL Database Engine 1.8.0.10
```

A split database setup does not contain the `database` directory.

The file `content.xml` contains database connection information.

```
<db:connection-data>
    <db:connection-resource xlink:href="sdbc:embedded:hsqldb" xlink:type="simple"/>
    <db:login db:is-password-required="false"/>
</db:connection-data>
```